# Delete file from a directory with php NO DATABASE

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am stuck on my codes from 2 days now. I have already tried more then 100 tutorials/guide but none of them solve my problem. Mostly guide is for database.

I am using ready made gallery plugin to display images on my website. This gallery does not use database. For that I made admin panel with upload function. Now i am looking for function to delete uploaded photos from admin panel. one pic at a time or multiple option will be more then good.

Right now with this code i am displaying images in Admin Page at main.php which i uploaded before:

```
<?php
$folder_path = 'gallery-images/'; //image's folder path

$num_files = glob($folder_path . "*.{jpeg,jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

$folder = opendir($folder_path);

if($num_files > 0)
{
 while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder))) 
 {
  $file_path = $folder_path.$file;
  $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if($extension=='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp') 
  {
   ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>" id="fname"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"  height="250" /></a>
            <?php
  }
 }
}
else
{
 echo "the folder was empty !";
}
closedir($folder);
?>
```

And i am trying this delete code in delete.php

```
<?php
$filename = $_POST['fname'];
$path = $_POST['directory'];
if(file_exists($path."/".$filename)) { 
 unlink($path."/".$filename); //delete file
}
?>
```

So i need a function to delete file from server with confirmation and with delete button. Right now file just open with a click. This function will be only for admin, So i think i am safe with delete function as i read in similar topics.

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT 1:**

So far this code successfully delete a file from server (Answer from @Jocelyn):

```
<h3><a href="?delete=1">Delete Now!</a></h3>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['delete']))
    {
        unlink(__FILE__);
    }
?>

Change this unlink(__FILE__); to unlink("$file_path");
```

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry, it does delete file from server but its deleting all the files in that directory.

Is there anyway to delete only one file which i click.

Right now all photos appearing from one link of code, i think thats the problem.

The link is this from which photos are appearing:

```
<a href="?delete=1" id="delete" name="delete"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"  height="250" /></a>
```

Comment: can you show us what you did try?

Comment: From where you get this `$_POST['fname']` and `$_POST['directory']`

Comment: ok, what are you asking, how to add/use a button? Does your code presently work? Do respond to comments here, otherwise take it up with answer(s). I for one won't stand around here forever.

Comment: @fred no, its not doing anything now, i am looking for a button to work or just click on image will do delete job.

Comment: so, add one? you have a choice between `<button>` and `<input>` as "submit" types.

Comment: @arunrc that was try only. i take from upload function.

Comment: After Googling "delete files with button php javascript" (for you), have found this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/13295307/1415724 being one of many. You really need to try something first and to show us what you did try. You mention that you tried hundreds of tutorials; ok good but how do we know what you did try doesn't contain (syntax) errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete file onclick with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295307/delete-file-onclick-with-php)

Comment: @fred button will be better option. i am trying for that only. as i said before i have seen this type of problem and tried lots of guid. Whatever right now i have is from that 100's of thing, which was not working in a way or two.

Answer (score 0):

A very quickly cobbled together example of how you might achieve your goal using ajax to send the filename to the `delete.php` script. No doubt that because it's not tested there may well be issues - but it's a starting point.

```
<?php
    /* delete.php */
    $img=!empty( $_GET['name'] ) ? $_GET['name'] : false;
    $result=false;


    if( $img ){
        /*

            here you would typically check that the path sent via ajax exists
            and then use unlink to delete the file before sending a response
            to the ajax callback function - the callback would then inform the
            user that the file has been deleted ( or not! )

            For testing though a simple message will suffice so that files are not deleted unnecessarily!!!

            -- uncomment the line below to actually attempt deletion of file.
        */


        if( file_exists( $img ) ){
            #$result = @unlink( $img );
            clearstatcache();
        }


        echo $result ? 'The file '.$img.' was deleted' : 'The file '.$img.' could not be deleted';
    }
?>




<?php
    $root='c:/wwwroot';
?>
<!-- /* admin page that lists images */ -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delete images - no database</title>
        <script>
            function ajax(imagename,callback){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.status==200 && xhr.readyState==4 ){
                        callback.call( this, xhr.response );
                    }
                };
                xhr.open( 'GET', 'delete.php?name='+imagename, true );
                xhr.send();
            }
            function deleteimage(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                ajax.call( this, e.target.dataset.path+'/'+e.target.dataset.name, cbdeleteimage );
            }
            function cbdeleteimage(r){
                alert( r );
            }
            function bindEvents(){
                var col=document.querySelectorAll('img.delete');
                for( var n in col )if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ) col[n].addEventListener( 'click', deleteimage, false );
            }

            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            $dir = 'gallery-images/';       /* YOUR path */
            $dir = $root . '/images/misc/'; /* MY test path */

            $files=preg_grep( '@(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.bmp|\.gif)@i', glob( $dir . '*.*' ) );
            $html=array();


            foreach( $files as $file ){
                if( $blocal ) $file=str_replace( $root, '', $file );    /* remove MY site root from file names */
                $name = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
                $path = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME );

                $html[]="<img class='delete' src='{$file}' data-name='{$name}' data-path='{$path}' />";
            }


            echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this but nothing happen. Photos display but when i click 1 empty popup then nothing.

Comment: I did notice a couple of mistakes - it was, like I say, cobbled together very quickly and not tested

Comment: anyway, thanks for your help. Can you able to help me out with redirection ? check my question again at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the final code which is perfectly fine for noobs like me who stuck with their work:

this is Delete.php to delete only a requested file

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['delete'];
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
    {
        unlink("./gallery-images/$file");
        header("Location:home.php");
    }
?>
```

This is upload.php to upload file with rename to auto increment value:

```
<?php

// Upload and Rename File

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
    $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $allowed_file_types = array('.png','.jpg','.jpeg');  
    $count = count (glob ('gallery-images/*'));

    if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 10000000))
    {   
        // Rename file
        $newfilename = ($count + 1) . $file_ext;
        if(file_exists("gallery-images/" . $newfilename))

        {
            // file already exists error
            echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
        }
        else
        {       
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "gallery-images/" . $newfilename);
            header("Location: home.php");   
            exit;
        }
    }
    elseif (empty($file_basename))
    {   
        // file selection error
        echo "Please select a file to upload.";
    } 
    elseif ($filesize > 10000000)
    {   
        // file size error
        echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";
    }
    else
    {
        // file type error
        echo "Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ',$allowed_file_types);
        unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    }
}

?>
```

This is home.php to display image with delete feature:

Upload Form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload: <br />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Display photos from directory:

```
<?php
$folder_path = 'gallery-images/'; //image's folder path 
$num_files = glob($folder_path . "*.{jpeg,jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
$folder = opendir($folder_path);
$file = '$file_path';

if($num_files > 0)
{
 while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder))) 
 {
  $file_path = $folder_path.$file;
  $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if($extension=='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'bmp') 
  {
   ?>
     <a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $file; ?>" onclick="return deleletconfig()" id="delete" name="delete"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"  height="175" /></a> 
<?php
  }
 }
}
else
{
 echo "the folder was empty !";
}
closedir($folder);
?>
```

Delete confirmation popup script:

```
<script>
function deleletconfig(){

var del=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
if (del==true){
}
return del;
}
</script>
```

Hope this will be helpful for learners.
Thanks.